# Changing mutableString of NSMutableAttributedString make attribute mapping strange

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I have to change UITextView's text but keep the mapping of attribute unchanged. But when I change the text, the attribute mapping also changed. For example

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableAttributedString *attString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"how are you"];

    [attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                  value:[UIColor redColor]
                  range:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
    [attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                  value:[UIColor greenColor]
                  range:NSMakeRange(1, 1)];
    [attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                  value:[UIColor blueColor]
                  range:NSMakeRange(2, 1)];
   self.textView.attributedText=attString;

}

- (IBAction)changeText
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *attString=[self.textView.attributedText mutableCopy];
    [attString.mutableString setString:@"Nice to meet you"];
    self.textView.attributedText=attString;
}
```

When changeText is triggered, I want "N" is red, "i" is green, "c" is blue. But the real result is the whole string is red. How can I change text but also keep mapping of attribute unchanged?

Comment: I don't think that's possible unless you copy the attributes, or maybe replace one by one the characters: `NSMutableAttributedString *newAttStr = [replaceString mutableCopy];
    [attString enumerateAttributesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [attString length]) options:0 usingBlock:^(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nonnull attrs, NSRange range, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) { [newAttStr addAttributes:attrs range:range];}];`?